# How to cancel previous Task if new request recieved?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, task-parallel-library, task, dotnet-httpclient

I will try to simplify my situation here to be more clean and concise. So, I am working on a **WinRT** application where user enters text in a `TextBox` and in its `TextChanged` event after 2 seconds have elapsed I need to make a remote request to fetch data based on user text.

Now user enters text and a web request has been initialized but immediately user writes another term. So, I need to cancel the first web request and fire the new one.

Consider the following as my code :

```cs
private CancellationTokenSource cts;

public HomePageViewModel()
{
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
}

private async void SearchPeopleTextChangedHandler(SearchPeopleTextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Cancel previous request before making new one        

    //GetMembers() is using simple HttpClient to PostAsync() and get response
    var members = await _myService.GetMembers(someId, cts.Token);

    //other stuff based on members
}
```

I know `CancellationToken` plays a role here but I just cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've already almost got it. The core idea is that a single `CancellationTokenSource` can only be canceled once, so a new one has to be created for each operation.

```
private CancellationTokenSource cts;

private async void SearchPeopleTextChangedHandler(SearchPeopleTextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  // If there's a previous request, cancel it.
  if (cts != null)
    cts.Cancel();

  // Create a CTS for this request.
  cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

  try
  {
    var members = await _myService.GetMembers(someId, cts.Token);

    //other stuff based on members
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException)
  {
    // This happens if this operation was cancelled.
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the CancellationTokenSource need to be disposed? And should that happen as soon as the call to _myService.GetMembers is finished so we don't cancel a previous token that is no longer needed?

Comment: @bmadtiger: A `CancellationTokenSource` should be either canceled or disposed. Since we always cancel the old one, disposal is unnecessary. Disposing `CancellationTokenSource`s can be messy because it causes some members to throw.

Comment: Thanks @stephen-cleary - I've been trying to do both `Cancel` and `Dispose` and getting exceptions with lots of repeated calls in a short frame of time because `CancellationTokenSource` was already disposed. That might explain it.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement the `GetMembers` method like this:

```
private async Task<List<Member>> GetMembers(int id, CancellationToken token)
    {
        try
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("http://apiendpoint"), content)
                                       .AsTask(token);
            }

            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            // Parse response and return result
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ocex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The rest is just calling the `cts.Cancel()` method and creating a new instance of `CancellationTokenSource` before calling `GetMembers` each time in the handler. Of course, as @Russell Hickey mentioned, `cts` should be global. (and even static if there are multiple instances of this class and you always want to cancel the `GetMembers` method when this handler is invoked. Usually I also have a class which wraps the result and has an additional property `IsSuccessful` to distinguish a real `null` result from a failed operation.